# How to setup Kibana SSO (through OAuth)?

Tags: oauth, single-sign-on, kibana

My company tries very hard to keep a SSO for all third party services. I'd like to make Kibana work with our Google Apps accounts. Is that possible? How?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From Elasticsearch, Kibana 5.0, shield plugin (security plugin) is embedded in [x-pack](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/x-pack/current/xpack-introduction.html) (paid service). So from Kibana 5.0 you can :

- use [X-Pack](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/x-pack/current/xpack-introduction.html)
- use [Search Guard](https://floragunn.com/)

Both these plugin can be used with basic authentication, so you can apply an Oauth2 proxy like [this one](https://github.com/bitly/oauth2_proxy). One additionnal proxy would forward the request with the right `Authorization` header with the digest `base64(username:password)`

The procedure is depicted in [this article](https://www.elastic.co/blog/user-impersonation-with-x-pack-integrating-third-party-auth-with-kibana) for x-pack. So you will have :

[image]

I've setup a docker-compose configuration in [this repo](https://github.com/bertrandmartel/kibana-oauth2-proxy) for using either searchguard or x-pack with Kibana/Elasticsearch 6.1.1 :

- [docker-compose for searchguard](https://github.com/bertrandmartel/kibana-oauth2-proxy/blob/master/searchguard/docker-compose.yml)
- [docker-compose for x-pack](https://github.com/bertrandmartel/kibana-oauth2-proxy/blob/master/xpack/docker-compose.yml)

Comment: X-Pack does not mean paid, just a different license (more restrictive, e.g. you can use it as long as you are using it for yourself, rather than hosting it for others - i.e. AWS)

Answer (score 4):

Kibana leaves it up to you to implement security.  I believe that Elastic's [Shield](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/shield/current/index.html) product has support for security-as-a-plugin, but I haven't navigated the subscription model or looked much into it.

The way that I handle this is by using an [oauth2 proxy application](https://github.com/bitly/oauth2_proxy) and use nginx to reverse proxy to Kibana.

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name kibana.example.org;

    # redirect http->https while we're at it
    rewrite ^ https://$server_name$request_uri? permanent;
}

server {
    # listen for traffic destined for kibana.example.org:443
    listen 443 default ssl;

    server_name  kibana.example.org;
    ssl_certificate /etc/nginx/ssl/cert.crt;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/ssl/cert.key.pem;
    add_header Strict-Transport-Security max-age=1209600;

    # for https://kibana.example.org/, send to our oauth2 proxy app
    location / {

        # the oauth2 proxy application i use listens on port :4180
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:4180;
        # preserve our host and ip from the request in case we want to
        # dispatch the request to a named nginx directive
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Scheme $scheme;
        proxy_connect_timeout 15;
        proxy_send_timeout 30;
        proxy_read_timeout 30;
    }
}
```

The request comes in, triggers an nginx directive that sends the request to the ouath application, which in turn handles the SSO resource and redirects to a listening Kibana instance on the server's localhost.  It's secure because connections cannot be made directly to Kibana.

Answer (score 0):

Use [oauth2-proxy](https://oauth2-proxy.github.io/oauth2-proxy/) application and Kibana with configured [anonymous authentication](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/kibana/8.6/kibana-authentication.html#anonymous-authentication) as on config below:

```
xpack.security.authc.providers:
  anonymous.anonymous1:
    order: 0
    credentials:
      username: "username"
      password: "password"
```

The user whose credentials are specified in the config can be created either via Kibana UI or [Elasticsearch create or update users API](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/security-api-put-user.html).

[image]

**Note!** Kibana instance should not be publicly available, otherwise anybody will be able to access Kibana UI. Only the oauth2-proxy instance can be publicly available.