# oauth2_proxy for basic auth login

Tags: elasticsearch, nginx, kibana, basic-authentication, oauth2-proxy

I'm trying to setup an OAuth2 authorizatin in front of my ELK installation.
I'm using [oauth2_proxy](https://oauth2-proxy.github.io/oauth2-proxy/). The idea is to use Google as SSO, extract the username from the SSO challenge, set this username as basic auth (with a fixed password) to log into Kibana.

I'm having difficulties to get the username and set it into the basic auth string. It seems that the variable `$remote_user` is not valued. If I hardcode a valid username:password it logs me in.

This is my configuration so far:

- oauth2_proxy running on port 4180
- nginx listening on 80/443 with a proxy pass to localhost:4180 (oauth2_proxy)
- oauth2_proxy that performs the SSO with localhost:8080 as upstream (nginx)
- nginx listening on 8080 with a proxy pass to localhost:5601 (kibana)

Something like this:

[image]

Here the conf file:

**oauth2_proxy launch string**

```
oauth2-proxy  
    --email-domain="example.com"  
    --upstream="http://127.0.0.1:8080/"  
    --approval-prompt="auto"  
    --redirect-url="https://example.com/oauth2/callback"  
    --cookie-secret=redacted
    --set-xauthrequest=true 
    --pass-user-headers=true 
    --pass-authorization-header=true
```

**oauth2_proxy.conf**

```
server {
    listen 443 ssl;
    server_name example.com;

    location / {
      proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:4180;
    }

    [letsencrypt config omitted]
}
```

**kibana.conf**

```
server {
    listen 8080;

    location / {
      proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:5601;

      set $auth_string  "${remote_user}:<my_strong-password>";
      set_encode_base64 $encoded_string $auth_string;

      proxy_set_header Authorization "Basic $encoded_string";

      #to manage logout redirect
      rewrite /login https://example.com/oauth2/sign_in redirect;
    }
}
```

My problem is that `${remote_user}` is empty, how can I valorize it? I've also tried with `$upstream_http_x_auth_request_user` and `$upstream_http_x_auth_request_email` with no luck.

Do you see any obvious errors?

Answer (score 0):

Why do you need to extract username if you specify fixed password in nginx config?

Instead you can enable anonymous access in Kibana config and get rid of nginx proxy. See this answer for details:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/75416817/3758005

Comment: Hi Oleksandr, thanks for your suggestion. I still need to check the username because not all my users need to access Kibana. I list them as a sort of white list.

Comment: By the way, I manager to solved it, but I forgot to add the answer. I'll do in the next days

Comment: he said a month ago ;)